# How to use one checkbox (IsChecked) to control another checkbox (IsEnabled) by binding function?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I use Visual Studio 2022 to create a WPF application. I have two checkboxes, `grade_4_CB` and `grade_4_centered_CB` in a Windows frame like this:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox Stretch=" fill">
            <Canvas Width=" 1100" Height=" 620">
                <CheckBox x:Name="grade_4_CB" Content="Grade 4" />
                <CheckBox x:Name="grade_4_centered_CB" Content="Grade 4 Centered"/> 
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, when I click `grade_4_CB` (IsChecked="True"), the `grade_4_centered_CB`'s `IsEnabled="True"`.

While not clicking of `grade_4_CB` (IsChecked="False"), the `grade_4_centered_CB`'s `IsEnabled="False"`

I tried to add behind `grade_4_centered_CB` like,

```
<CheckBox x:Name="grade_4_centered_CB" Content="Grade 4 Centered">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grade_4_CB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grade_4_CB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

However, I get an error,

> Error XLS0415: No attachable property 'Style' found on type 'CheckBox'

Another method is replacing `<CheckBox.Style>` to `<CheckBox.Resources>` but I get a similar error.

Besides, I also tried to modify directly the property of `grade_4_centered_CB` in right column (common-IsEnable-data bindingdialog), find and add `grade_4_CB` -path(IsChecked), but no matter False string or True string, there is no change in `grade_4_centered_CB`

Comment: I am novice in C#.Net so any advice is helpful for me, thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have an error in something else. Your styling option is correct and should work correctly.
I checked it like this:

```xml
<Window ---------------
        --------------->
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width=" 1100" Height=" 620">
            <CheckBox x:Name="grade_4_CB" Content="Grade 4" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="grade_4_centered_CB" Content="Grade 4 Centered">
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <!--This trigger for True is superfluous. It can be removed.-->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grade_4_CB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grade_4_CB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The same behavior can be achieved without style triggers. Using only binding.

```xml
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width=" 1100" Height=" 620">
            <CheckBox x:Name="grade_4_CB" Content="Grade 4" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="grade_4_centered_CB" Content="Grade 4 Centered"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=grade_4_CB}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```